# AngularJS Expression not displaying the data from service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I suspect it is an incorrectly written expression or the way the controller is fetching data from the service. By the way, the controller has been tested and it works just fine. 
Please help.

Here is my view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Installing the ngRoute module -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="SuggestionBox">
    <div class="suggestion" ng-controller="HomeController">
        <div class="container" ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <h2 class="title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
<!-- Services -->
<script src="js/services/suggestions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the service where I am fetching the data from

```
app.factory('suggestions', [function() {
var demoSuggestions = {
    posts: [
        {
            title: "bla bla bla",
        },
        {
            title: "blo blo blo",
        }
    ]
};
return demoSuggestions;
}]);
```

This is the controller

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'suggestions', function($scope, suggestions) {
$scope.posts = suggestions.demoSuggestions;
}]);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: How you define angular module? What is `app` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In service you should assign `posts` which has been return in `suggestions` factory object.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'suggestions', 
  function($scope, suggestions) {
     $scope.posts = suggestions.posts;
  }
]);
```

[**Demo here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/McpKyZQq3vHz3CYrcIBD?p=preview)

**Update**

You app.js should define module like below

```
var  app = angular.module('SuggestionBox',[])
```

**Edit**

I made last plunkr to demonstrate the issue which were faced by OP. So ideally you should follow [angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) made by John Papa

Here you need to wrap each component code to IIFE pattern like

```
(function(){
  //code here
})()
```

And do define angular `module` once and used them afterwards, avoid creating global variables.

Comment: @HumbertoTellechea look at the updated answer.. I had added demo, which seems to be working fine..

Comment: `app` as global variable ; / It is time to introduce modules and pass them as dependencies.

Comment: please consider to read this styleguide. avoid globals. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: @Sombriks yes. I did that because make OP closer to find his own mistake.. Thanks for heads up..I updated the answer